# Django-Tastypie filter all fields

Tags: tastypie

I'm doing a project with django-tastypie and know how to set a field to filter by, thus:

filtering = {
       'nationality': ALL,
}

What I want to know is if there was some setting that would allow me to have all the fields available for filtering, without having to be set one by one as in the example above?

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I Don't think there is a way to do it at once.
You can use this way,

```
for field in YourModel.__dict__['_meta'].fields:
    filtering.update({field.name : ALL})
```